# Adaptive card custom action in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, adaptive-cards

I am trying to create custom action in adaptive card but not able to create it. could anyone please help me out

Card Data

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "size": "Medium",
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "text": "Custom"
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.Alert",
            "title": "Click me",
            "text": "Hello world!"
        }
    ]
}
```

TypeScript file - action.ts created newly

```
import * as AC from "adaptivecards";
export class AlertAction extends AC.Action {
    static readonly JsonTypeName = "Action.Alert";

    //#region Schema

    static readonly textProperty = new AC.StringProperty(AC.Versions.v1_0, "text", true);

    @AC.property(AlertAction.textProperty)
    text?: string;

    //#endregion

    getJsonTypeName(): string {
        return AlertAction.JsonTypeName;
    }

    execute() {
        alert(this.text);
    }
}
```

and as per the this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/sdk/rendering-cards/javascript/extensibility
I am not getting where to add this line of code

AC.GlobalRegistry.actions.register(AlertAction.JsonTypeName, AlertAction);

This is the code to render the card

```
var jsonTemplate = "some data",
  var jsonDate = "some data"
var template = new ACData.Template(jsonTemplate);
var cardPayload = template.expand({
  $root: jsonData
});
var adaptiveCard = new AdaptiveCards.AdaptiveCard();
adaptiveCard.onExecuteAction = function(action) {
  alert("Ow!");
}
adaptiveCard.parse(cardPayload);
let renderedCard = adaptiveCard.render();
document.body.appendChild(renderedCard);
```

---

I tried by adding GlobalRegistry like this

```
 import {AlertAction} from '../action' // Action file is a TS file 
    var adaptiveCard = new AdaptiveCards.AdaptiveCard();
            adaptiveCard.onExecuteAction = function(action) {
  alert("Ow!");
}
            adaptiveCard.GlobalRegistry.actions.register(AlertAction.JsonTypeName, AlertAction)
```

I am getting error like "ReferenceError: Cannot access 'AlertAction' before initialization"

Comment: You need the line wherever you initialize the renderer, before you render the card. AC. in this case is the renderer instance.

Comment: Hi @TimCadenbach, i have added card rendering code above...this rendering code in js file but the line AC.GlobalRegistry.actions.register(AlertAction.JsonTypeName, AlertAction) needs to be added in the type script file as per the docs.. now how can we use this line in js file..please help me on this

Comment: Been ages since i tried that but as far as i know you have to set it on the "var adaptiveCard"

As in after the onExecuteAction you set the GlobalRegistry actions etc. Can't try it right now but will later today